# How do I check if a Decimal is positive or negative in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to check if a Decimal number is negative. Tried:

```
if value._isNegative {
...
}
```

But it gives the error `'UInt32' is not convertible to 'Bool'`

Answer (score 20):

### Swift 5 solution

```
let value: Double = -5.0
value.sign == .minus ? print("negative") : print("positive")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with an integer.

Answer (score 13):

Try using value < 0. This will check if the value is less than 0.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Found out that it can also be: `value.isSignMinus`